# chrome inject html doesn't work and no error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to inject html (a modal) into any url but failed, I got no error in my background page console.

What I did was below :
in my manifest.json I declare `"web_accessible_resources": ["modal.html"]` and include my background script by `"background" : { "scripts": ["jquery.js","script.js"] }`

In my script.js I do

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('modal.html'), function(data) {
             $($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');
        });
```

It has no error returned but I can't see the html block got injected. I run `console.log(data)` I can see the html block, that's strange.

Comment: You're not injecting anything. You're making an AJAX request to `modal.html`, which returns the HTML in plain text format to your background script. There, you parse that text as HTML, and make some changes to it. You then append it to `body` - but the `body` of your background page, which you never see. That's as if I was to download the HTML of stackoverflow.com, save it to `stack.html` and make some changes to it. stackoverflow.com would be entirely unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is failure to understand [the extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Your data is probably added correctly - to the background page itself.

The only part of the extension that can manipulate DOM of visible pages are [the content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). If you change your manifest record to

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "js": ["jquery.js","script.js"],
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
}]
```

you'll probably see the results as expected.

Comment: I figured it out, I shouldn't put the js into background, should put at contentscript, thanks!

Comment: I injected my modal, but failed to interact with it. In my background.js I run $('#modal).length it show zero, why? the DOM existed.

Comment: Please read the pages I linked. You need to understand the concepts.

Comment: chrome.contextMenus.create() should run at contentScript not background.js? I don't think so, I got an error doing that. I think I have to pass the trigger from background.js to contentScript.js, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There are many things content scripts are not allowed to do, as a security measure. You need to pass a request to your background.